# Block chain receive payment api not working

Tags: blockchain.info, api, java

I am building a little online app to accept bitcoin payments in my website. I have a blockchain.info wallet and I am following their Receive Payments Api, which can be visited here: http://blockchain.info/api/api_receive

The monetary part works great, but the HTTP Callback Notification does not take place and my online store is not notified of the payment. However, the TEST callback does work.

I think it is a problem on his application.

Has anyone implemented the "Receive Money API" successfully?
Is there any other alternative for received instant payment notifications? (To several different addresses)
A friend of mine reports the same issue. We need a little help :)